# how to remove this symbol after the Consultation Charges

Tags: html

Hi in the below code I am getting this Consultation Charges: but after this heading it showing this symbol.I want to remove that how to do can any one help me form this issue

Expected output:

Main heading
   subheading| ->how to remove this |

**updated html**

```
    <table width="100%" border="1" style="width:100%;border-collapse: collapse;text-align:center">
        <tr>
            <th width="12.5%"><b>Bill Particular</b></th>
            <th width="12.5%"><b>Bill Sub Particular</b></th>
            <th width="12.5%"><b>Doctor</b></th>
            <th width="12.5%"><b>Date</b></th>
            <th width="12.5%"><b>Dis. Amt.</b></th>
            <th width="12.5%"><b>Charge</b></th>
            <th width="12.5%"><b>No. of Times</b></th>
            <th width="12.5%"><b>Amount</b></th><br>
        </tr>
        <tr width="100%"><th colspan=2>Consultation Charges:</th><br>

        </tr><br>   
        </table>
```

Comment: you mean bold Bill Particular,Bill Sub Particular ??

Comment: @SajadKaruthedath for whole table headings

Comment: Please make the question more readable. It is difficult to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of  tag which displays the text like a heading..

Ex:

```
<html>
       <table>
            <tr>
               <th>Bill Particular</th>
               <td>Values</td>
            </tr>
       </table>
</html>
```